# How to improve "on keyup" speed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onkeyup

Here is my code:

```
$('#MyInput').on('keyup', function (e) {
      if ($(this).val().length == 1) {
          ajaxSearch($(this).val());
     }
});
```

I want to run a function when the `input` has only one character.

The problem is that if the user type a word really fast, the `'keyup'` event seems to be called starting from the second character, which means it will not call `ajaxSearch()` method.

Is there any way to improve the `'keyup'` event speed to call the function when it has only 1 character?

Comment: Can't imagin it being triggered at the second character... it's the releasing of the first character you are detecting. Maybe you want keydown (keypress)?

Comment: What about a paste?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When user types too fast, **he/she may have not released the previous key yet**, so `keyup` technically hasn't happened yet.

Try `keypress` instead of `keyup`

```
$('#MyInput').on('keypress', function (e) {
      if ($(this).val().length == 1) {
          ajaxSearch($(this).val());
     }
});
```

**Edit**

On `keypress` `input`'s `value` property has not be been updated yet, so catch `keyup` as well **in case user only inputs a single character**.

```
$('#MyInput').on('keypress', function (e) {
      if ($(this).val().length == 1) {
          ajaxSearch($(this).val());
     }
});
```

```js
$('#MyInput').on('keyup keypress', function(e) {
  if ($(this).val().length == 1) {
    ajaxSearch($(this).val(),e);
  }
});

function ajaxSearch(value,e) {
  console.log(value, e.type)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="MyInput">
```

Comment: Ok... but when i use `keypress`, the method   `ajaxSearch($(this).val());` doesn't  get the correct parameter because at the moment the key is pressed the character is not in the input yet.

Comment: @JoaoWind I have attached a demo with some modifications which should handle all scenarios.

Answer (score 5):

Try keypress instead of keyup

```
$('#MyInput').on('keypress', function (e) {
      if ($(this).val().length == 1) {
          ajaxSearch($(this).val());
     }
});
```